# How to authenticate windows client with Ldap server on Linux with share home directory

Tags: ldap, openldap

I want to configure LDAP server on Linux (centos is most preferable) and I want to authenticate from my windows client to that LDAP server (on Linux) and also I want that home folder of the windows user must be stored on LDAP server (on Linux).

So how can I achieve this setup? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need more than an LDAP server, as Windows clients are relying on more services than just LDAP.
Look at Samba Servers on Linux.